# VSTS database schema comparison not saving comments

Tags: database-tools

We use VSTS 2008 with SP1 and GDR R2 installed.

Found the next problem:

1. 2 identical databases (for example
   Database1 and Database2);
2. Database1 is a working database,
   Database2 is a production one;
3. adding a new stored procedure to the
   Database1 with comments
   (description, author etc. before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement);
4. trying to compare schemes on
   Database1 (source) and Database2
   (target); the new SP successfully
   added to the Database2 but without comment above the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement (but comments in the SP body are fully preserved).

The part of the stored procedure in Database1:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      [author here]
-- Create date: [creation date here]
-- Description: [description here]
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema here].[procedure name here] 
    @param1 uniqueidentifier,
    @param2 nvarchar(64),
    @param3 bit,
    @param4 int = 1,
    @param5 int = 25,
    @param6 int = 0 output,
    @param7 int = 0 output
AS
```

The result in Database2 after schema comparison:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema here].[procedure name here]
@param1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @param2 NVARCHAR (64), @param3 BIT, @param4 INT=1, @param5 INT=25, @param6 INT=0 OUTPUT, @param7 INT=0 OUTPUT
AS
```

It murdered comments.
The check mark in the `Schema compare options... -> Ignore Comments` is unchecked.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered having read something about this a while ago, and after a little digging I found [this blog post by Gert Drapers](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/12/19/handling-of-comments-in-the-gdr.aspx), a.k.a. The Datadude, which describes your exact problem. He says that it is a known problem and that the team is working on a fix. The post dates back to before the GDR2 was released, so I guess they haven't fixed it yet since you still have this problem.

Comment: Thank you! I read a lot of related stuff but didn't find this article.